# Read csv file in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, csv, path

I have this code to read a csv file

```
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:outError];
if (!fileString) {
NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
}
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileString];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSetcharacterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n#; "]];

NSString *id = nil, *hashOne = nil, *hashTwo = nil, *hashThree = nil, *hashFour = nil;
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&id] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"# intoString:&hashOne] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&hashTwo] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&hashThree] && [scanner scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&hashFour]) {
 // Process the values as needed.
 NSLog(@"id:%@, 1:%@, 2:%@, 3:%@:, 4:%@", id, hashOne, hashTwo, hashThree, hashFour);
}
```

but my file csv don't have a path but it's in xcode project folder...what can I solve?

Comment: How are you creating path for your csv file? one way is '[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aFile" ofType:@"csv"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NSBundle pathForResource:ofType: method, for a given file name (resourceFileName):

```
pathToFile = [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: resourceFileName ofType: @"csv"];
```

Comment: there is a warning in outError...how I can declare "outError"??